# Editing associeted resources in rails; How to find an object by id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

1) When I use link "Edit" in edit.html.erb its fields are filled by atributes of the first object(`task`). As if I use the method `.first` instead the method `.find(id)`.
But I need to edit an appropriate object, not always the first object.

I tried to change in TasksController:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@task = @project.tasks.find_by(project_id: params[:id])
```

in this way:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
```

and received:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#edit (Couldn't find
>   Task with 'id')

When tried to change `<%= form_for  [@project, @task] do |f| %>` on `<%= form_for @task do |f| %>`, I received:

> NoMethodError in Tasks#edit (undefined method `task_path')

Then i tried to change link in show.html.erb and:

2) If I push the button "Update Task" i receive:

> NoMethodError in TasksController#update (undefined method `update' for
>   nil:NilClass)

in string:

```
@task.update(task_params)
```

Is the mistake in the definition of path to the object?

the source:

TasksController

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find_by(project_id: params[:id])
end

def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find_by(project_id: params[:id])

    @task.update(task_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

private
def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :status)
end

end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Add a task:</h2>

<%= form_for  [@project, @task] do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  ...
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

projects/show.html.erb

```
...
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy task', [task.project, task],
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                 |
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_task_path(@project) %> 
  </p>

...
```

routes

```
    welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                       welcome#index
    project_tasks GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
                  POST   /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
 new_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
edit_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
     project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
                  PATCH  /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                  PUT    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                  DELETE /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
         projects GET    /projects(.:format)                            projects#index
                  POST   /projects(.:format)                            projects#create
      new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                        projects#new
     edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                   projects#edit
          project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#show
                  PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                  PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                  DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#destroy
             root GET    /                                              welcome#index
```

Thank you in advance.

Duplicate ru.stackoverflow:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690120/219253

Comment: Can you post the params that are generated in the log when you click on Edit?

Comment: Try with your `form_for` like: `form_for([@task.project, @task])` and your `edit` method like: `def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
  end` what do you get?

Comment: @Sebastián Palma, I get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#edit  Couldn't find Task with 'id'=13 [WHERE "tasks"."project_id" = $1]` Extracted source `@task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very specific way we work with a model that belongs to another model in Rails. This requires an understanding of how forms, controllers, models, and views work in rails.

You have this declaration in rails:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
end
```

This code is saying that the resource `task` belongs to the resource `project`. In other words, all of the tasks have an associated project, and when you are interacting with `tasks`, there is always a `/projects/:project_id` prepended to the URI. The resulting routes structure is in your question.

That being said, in your `tasks` controller, the proper way to get the `Project` that you are working with is:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
```

And, if you are modifying or accessing an existing `Task` object (`:edit, :update, :destroy, :show`), a way to access that `Task` object is:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
```

Now, the proper way to code the form is this:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @task] do |f| %>
```

This tells the form that you are modifying/creating a `@task` that belongs to `@project`. Depending on whether you are creating or modifying a `Task`, the `form_form` method renders a form that interacts with a different controller method.

You were receiving the `NoMethodError in Tasks#edit` because you changed the way you coded the form from the right way to the wrong way (not specifying what project the task belonged to).

You were probably receiving the `NoMethodError in TasksController#update for nil:NilClass` because you were accessing the task the wrong way, and therefore having a `nil` `@task`.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT 7/12/2017 from  @Yaraslau Khamenka**

Also, you need to provide the project that is associated with the task you are editing in the `link_to`:

```
edit_project_task_path(@project, @task)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I began to understand the situation a little better. But, if i try code `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id]), @task = Task.find(params[:id])` in edit-action and `<%= form_for [@project, @task] do |f| %>` in form... I get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#edit Couldn't find Task with 'id'=13`. May be the cause is in database or magic.. May I provide some more info?..

Comment: That just means that you are trying to edit a task object that doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: I tryed delleted my db and created it again: `db:drop:all` `db:create:all` `db:migrate`. Now I always get "taks id" = "project id". if project id = 1, task id always = 1 too (if project id = 2, task id = 2). when i try edit some task. If i destroyed some project or some task i am again get error `Couldn't find Task with 'id'`.

Comment: I was told that I have an error in passing parameters in link. Need `<% = link_to 'Edit task', [: edit, task.project, task]%>`.

Comment: Ah, you're right! Sorry, I completely forgot about that. I've updated the answer above!